# Finite queue transition probabilities with geometric exits

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains, queueing-theory

A server system with a finite queue is the following Markovian system: the state is defined as the length of the queue. At each time unit with probability $p$ regardless of the system’s state and other jobs, a new job is added. Unless the queue is full (with $N$ jobs) then the new job is disregarded and forgotten. The time it takes to accomplish a job is a geometric random variable with probability $q$, which has the following pmf:
$$f(k) = \begin{cases} q(1-q)^k & k \geq 0, \\ 0 & k<0 \end{cases}$$
I need to draw the state diagram for $N =4$, but my computations don’t match the answers of $p (1-q)$.

 **My attempt**:
$$ P_{i,i+1} = P(\{\text{job not complete}\} \cup \{\text{new job}\}) =\\ p \cdot P(k \neq 1)= \\ p(1 - (1-q)q)=\\p (1-q-q^2) \neq p (1-q)$$
I don’t see what I’m doing wrong here. My other calculations are similarly not matching.

**Other results according to the answers:**
$$
\begin{align}
P_{N,N-1} &= 1 - (1-p)q\\
P_{i,i-1} &= q(1-p)\\
P_{00} &= 1 - p(1-q)\\
P_{ii} &= 1 - p(1-q)-(1-p)q
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the question is using the other definition of Geometric Random Variable, that is, $f(k)=(1-q)^{k-1}q$ for $k\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Now you should get your answer of $P(i$ people in queue at time $t$, $i + 1$ people in queue at time $t+1) = p(1-q)$.

Comment: They gave me the definition I've written in the body of the question though

Comment: Alright. In this case, can you also give details of the other calculations that don't match the question please? You should edit your question to do this.

Comment: Yes - will do asap - in 15ish hours tops

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DkF0npg the official answers for the other transition probabilities - for edge state 0 i added the probability of solved job to redirect to 0 and for N=4 i added the probability of new job to redirect to 4

Comment: What do you mean by "$1-$"? And why is there a comma inside the last equation?

Comment: i think it’s a print error https://imgur.com/a/pkN2mg1 here’s what i think it should be

Comment: the last bit slipped over to the next line

Comment: It seems like the answer's $P_{i,i-1}, P_{00}, P_{ii}$ are all consistent with my explanation above. However, the $P_{N,N-1}$ did not make sense to me.

Comment: I'll double back to this question and try your method and see if I can identify what went wrong.